# How to determine external component is loaded and get its required data in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi i have a situation where i'm developing a plugin or extension, wherein for main component i cannot add any code except `mixins`

my situation is something like this:

i have 2 components (1) `actions-comp` (2) `display-comp`

once action component button is clicked display component must show up and display component will get a imageUrl that i want to get in actions component

**Question:** i want to get the `imgUrl` from `display-comp` into `actions-comp` once `imgUrl` is set.

**Note:** the `actions-comp` can go into any level of component nesting but `display-comp` will remain within main component

**here is what i have tried:**

for better view codepen: https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/ExXLXwv

```js
const globalMixin = {
  data(){
    return {
        displayDetails:{
          show:false,
        }
    }
  }
}

const comp2 = {
     name:'actions-comp',
     template:`<button @click="displayThumbnail()">Generate and Display image</button>`,
     methods:{
       displayThumbnail(){
          this.$parent.displayDetails.show = true;
          // 1. get url of image from 'display-comp'
          // 2. print them or send 
          console.log(`the image url of display-comp is:`);
       }
     }
}

const comp3 = {
     name:'display-comp',
     template:`<img src="" id="img" width="150px" height="80px" style="border:1px solid red;"/>`,
     data(){
       return {
           imgUrl:'',
           imgLoaded:false,
       }
     },
    mounted(){
      //mimick the server response don't know how much time server will take
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.imgUrl = `https://via.placeholder.com/150`
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src',this.imgUrl);
          this.imgLoaded = true;
        });
      }, 500);
    },

    beforeDestroy(){
       this.imgLoaded = true;
   }
}


const app = new Vue({
   el:'#app',
   name:'app',
   mixins:[globalMixin],
   components:{'actions-comp':comp2,'display-comp':comp3},
});

console.log('app',app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  
  
    <display-comp v-if="displayDetails.show"></display-comp ref="display">
  
   <actions-comp><actions-comp/>
 
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is naturally solved with Vue 3 suspense. In Vue 2 it's generally a mistake to delegate this job to a child. Move the request to a parent and provide a child with ready to use data. As a workaround, you can emit something like `ready` event from a child. The use of `$parent` indicates that component design went wrong, it was bad even in AngularJS where it was borrowed from.

Comment: I would use the store for this kind of use-case